# How can I make a list of adjacent letters of a string?

Tags: python, list

I am looking for a way to get a cartesian product of a string in the following form,

```
text = 'school'
```

I want the result like this,

```
list_ = [(s,c),(c,h),(h,o),(o,o),(o,l)]
```

this is what I tried,

```
text = 'school'
list_=[]
for i in range(len(text)):
  while i < len(text)+1:
    print(text[i], text[i+1])
    list_.append((text[i], text[i+1]))
    i = i+1
```

I got the necessary list, yet throwing off some errors. Is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: `[(text[i], text[i+1]) for i,c in enumerate(text[:-1])]`

Comment: That isn't anything at all like a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text = 'school'
list(zip(text, text[1:]))

Out[1]:
[('s', 'c'), ('c', 'h'), ('h', 'o'), ('o', 'o'), ('o', 'l')]
```